# Save firebase timestamp value using admin SDK

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to save date as firebase timestamp format.
I am doing this in cloudFunctions using admin SDK.

Here is what I am trying:

```
deactivationDate: moment().toDate(),
deactivationDate1:  new Date(),
deactivationDate2 : admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
```

When I retrieve this record on client, I get :

```
deactivationDate: {_seconds: 1597421671, _nanoseconds: 993000000}
deactivationDate1: {_seconds: 1597421671, _nanoseconds: 993000000}
deactivationDate2: {_seconds: 1597421671, _nanoseconds: 993000000}
```

I am wondering why it is sending me `_seconds and _nanoseconds` (with underscore)

I am not able to convert this value to date because of **_** i think.

Comment: "When I retrieve this record on client, I get..." This depends on how you retrieve them on the client. Please edit your question to show the code of how you read and write the timestamp.

Comment: actually your comment made me realize a stupid mistake.  I was retrieving data from CloudFunctions as well and I forgot to do 'deactivationDate: userDoc.deactivationDate?.toMillis()'

Comment: Consider me your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) for today then. :)   So problem solved?

Comment: haha it wasn't the first time you were my rubber duck. problem is solved. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get proper timestamp value in form of Milliseconds.

The problem was I was not converting it toMillis() when retrieving from my cloud function.

I have a cloud function retrieving users like this:

```
    admin
              .firestore()
              .collection("users")
              .where(query)
              .get();    
    const propertyIdUsers: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData[] = [];
                propertyIdUsersSnapshot.forEach((p) => {
                  const userDoc = p.data();
                  propertyIdUsers.push({
                    ...userDoc,
                    createdAt: userDoc.createdAt?.toMillis(),
                    updatedAt: userDoc.updatedAt?.toMillis(),
                    deactivationDate: userDoc.deactivationDate?.toMillis(), // I needed to convert toMillis() right here before going to client. 
// This way client receives milliseconds that will work with moment js. 
                  });
                });
```

Thanks to @Frank van Puffelen's comment for redirecting me to that solution.